# Checkbox value always getting posted even when not checked

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am adding a checkbox to my form using:

```
$fieldset->addField($value, 'checkbox', array(
                    'label'     => $label,
                    'name'      => $value,
                    'checked' => false,
                    'onclick' => "",
                    'onchange' => "",
                    'value'  => $value,
                    'disabled' => false,
                    'tabindex' => 1
                ));
```

Then in my controller I am doing:

```
if (isset($this->post[$value]))
                {
                    $webCategory = $this->post[$value];
                    if ($webCategory != '') {
                        Mage::log("Syncing: " . $webCategory);
                    }
                }
```

`$this->post` is the `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost()` from the page. `$value` contains the id of the checkbox (all the data is dynamic so I have posted snippets).

The issue I have is that the checkbox values are always getting logged even when I don't tick them. I always thought checkboxes weren't posted unless they were ticked. Am I losing it or does Magento do something odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your browser: What data get POSTed? The network tab of your browser's debugger (e.g. Firebug for Firefox) will tell you. Are the checkboxes data in there?

Second, check the HTML: Are the checkbox names defined multiple times? That might be the reason for them to show up in your POST data.

Comment: Doh! I forgot I had some other dynamic controls on another tab and it turns out I was using the same name / ID. Thanks for that (only 9:40 am and already losing it .. great).